# I can only post to MY (developer) twitter using Twitter4J?

Tags: twitter

I feel like I am missing something quite crucial and obvious here.. I have managed to implement Twitter4J into my application. I set up the OAuthConsumerKey, Secret, Token and Token Secret from the details of the app I made in Twitter. Now, when I post images or tweets, they all are posted from the Twitter I use and made the app with. Is that correct? How can I get people to tweet stuff from their own accounts?

Thanks!

Comment: In short, you'll need to build a workflow to let users give consent to your app to read/write to their twitter accounts. Twitter will return oauth token/secret for each user that you'll need to save and supply respectively when you call twitter on a given user's behalf.

Comment: can this all be done with twitter4j?

Comment: Yes, since twitter4j supports OAuth for calling Twitter APIs. The workflow is more about building UX/UI for users to give consent to your app (offline would be simpler than online), infra to store/retrieve their app specific tokens and calling twitter APIs with rate limit considerations etc.